# Implement Brightcove player in android native app

Tags: android

I just wanna implement Brightcove player in android.i referred from

http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/accessing-video-content-media-api

http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/best-practices-android-app-development

From that., i got video url as " http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_video_by_id&video_id=1520880903001&video_fields=name,length,FLVURL&media_delivery=http&token=jskS1rEtQHy9exQKoc14IcMq8v5x2gCP6yaB7d0hraRtO__6HUuxMg.. "

On tht i got VideoId,Video_fields for a particular video on videocloud.I just want to play that video using those informations on brightcove player in android native app.

My code:

private static final String MyApiToken = "My Token";
        private ReadAPI mReadAPI = new ReadAPI(MyApiToken);
        private com.brightcove.mobile.mediaapi.model.Video pVideo;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    makeAPICall();

}
```

private void makeAPICall() {

```
    Log.d("Sample", "Beginning makeAPICall");
    EnumSet<VideoFieldEnum> videoFields = VideoFieldEnum.createEmptyEnumSet(); 
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.NAME);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.LENGTH);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.FLVURL);

    try {
        long videoId =My videoId;
        pVideo = mReadAPI.findVideoById(videoId, videoFields, null);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
        Log.e("Sample", msg);
    }

    //Create the player
    BCPlayerView mPlayer;
    mPlayer = (BCPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);

    mPlayer.load(pVideo);
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

}

Ive added library jars like bc-android-mediapi.jar & bc-android-player.jar also.When i tried to run.,I got black screen with video player controller visible.But video is not playing.Anything i need to include further?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I stubbled on it while searching for the same answer.

Here is how I solved it:

1. Make sure that your app has permission to access the Internet

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```
2. Using the Read API token key with URL Access ([How to get this token](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/managing-media-api-tokens#view))
3. By forcing the media delivery type to be H264

   ```
    theReadAPI.setMediaDeliveryType(MediaDeliveryTypeEnum.HTTP);
   ```

Hope this helps anyone else having problems with this library. Here is my full code sample:

```
    Logger mAPILogger = Logger.getLogger("BCAndroidAPILogger");
    ReadAPI theReadAPI = new ReadAPI("read with URL Access token");
    theReadAPI.setMediaDeliveryType(MediaDeliveryTypeEnum.HTTP);
    theReadAPI.setLogger(mAPILogger);

    EnumSet<VideoFieldEnum> videoFields = VideoFieldEnum
            .createEmptyEnumSet();
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.ID);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.NAME);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.LENGTH);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.RENDITIONS);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.FLVURL);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.THUMBNAILURL);
    videoFields.add(VideoFieldEnum.VIDEOFULLLENGTH);

    try {
        // Get My Playlist
        Playlist thePlaylist = theReadAPI.findPlaylistById(1234567890123,
                videoFields, null, null);

        BCPlayerView thePlayer = (BCPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
        thePlayer.logEnabled(true);
        thePlayer.load(thePlaylist.getVideos().get(0));
        thePlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```